# Upload File With Powershell using Response Stream

Tags: powershell, upload

I'm having a problem here trying to upload a file with powershell.  What I'm trying to do is shoot a .zip file to a target user account on a destination server.  Destination server is running IIS FTP 7.5 and has user isolation enabled with a datachannel port range of 5500-6500 (if that might matter).

Here's my code below - the problem is I get that I cannot call a method on a null-valued expression on the `$responsestream` request.  Please let me know if I goofed up, looking all over the net... have had so many problems uploading files!

Also I want to say I used a download script that I'm converting to upload since I haven't had any success with the upload scripts I've tried out before.

```
$targetpath = "ftp://10.21.109.202/Recieve/account_apps.zip"
$sourceuri = "D:\AccountManager\Send\$RTMPHOST\account_apps.zip"
$username = "AccountManager"
$password = "test"

# Create a FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the ftp server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($sourceuri)

# set the request's network credentials for"

#an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

# send the ftp request to the server
$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()

# get a download stream from the server response
$responsestream = $ftpresponse.GetRequestStream()

# create the target file on the local system and the download buffer
$targetfile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($targetpath,[IO.FileMode]::Create)
[byte[]]$readbuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024

# loop through the download stream and send the data to the target file
do{
    $readlength = $responsestream.Read($readbuffer,0,1024)
    $targetfile.Write($readbuffer,0,$readlength)
}
while ($readlength -ne 0)

$targetfile.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach to uploading a file to an URI using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) class:

```
$targetUri = "ftp://10.21.109.202/Recieve/account_apps.zip"
$sourcePath = "D:\AccountManager\Send\$RTMPHOST\account_apps.zip"
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

$client.UploadFile($targetUri, $sourcePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a response for the upload.
The FTP Protocol dont use round trips.

```
$stream = $ftprequest.GetRequestStream()

$stream.Write(...)

$stream.Close()

$ftpresponse= $ftprequest.GetResponse()
#... is success?
$ftpresponse.Close()
```

The response AFTER the request (with all bytes) 
would be the upload success or fail.